# Grant AppOps permissions to system apps in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, system, android-permissions, android-app-ops

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422587/android-marshmallow-dangerous-protection-level-and-system-components-apps), starting from Android 6.0 Marshmallow, system apps are no longer granted dangerous permissions by default. I also read that only apps signed with the platform key have the old behavior.
Is there a way to add other apps to "trusted" ones? Is it possible, as a ROM developer, to add another trusted key beside the platform one?

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468