# Android runtime permission for system apps

Tags: android, android-source, runtime-permissions

Question about Android runtime permissions. AFAIK, android grant dangerous permission at runtime. I reset my phone, then adb pull /data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml, I found android.ui.system has already granted many dangerous permissions. can anybody tell me how it does?

Comment: there are some permissions which doesn't need to be granted Refer here for detail:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-new-runtime-permissions/

Comment: thanks Jagjit. 
this is part of runtime-permissions.xml,

<shared-user name="android.uid.system">
    <item name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" granted="true" flags="30" />
    <item name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" granted="true" flags="30" />
    <item name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" granted="true" flags="30" />
    <item name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" granted="true" flags="30" />
    <item name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" granted="true" flags="30" />

Comment: as you can see, these permissions are dangerous permissions, they should be granted at runtime. but they have been granted when first boot, it's confused.

Comment: have you upgraded your device from 5 to 6 ?

Comment: My Device is Android 6.0.1. should it because system set default runtime permission for "android.uid.system" somewhere? because this is a special system uid.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The mechanism to insert [dangerous runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous_permissions) into the `/data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml` file via a user-confirmed dialog applies only to third party applications, and is not relevant for built-in applications.

> For built-in/system applications and framework components, all
>   permissions are granted by default **when a new user is created or
>   when the device boots and a `systemReady` event is fired**.

You can see the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) from AOSP, where all types of required permissions are written for system components.

For third party apps, when the user grants any runtime permission, it gets added into the file `/data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml`. The permission gets removed from the file when the user revokes it from any third party app. In the case of a full factory reset, runtime permissions of all third party apps are removed, as `/data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml` gets deleted (data partition wipe).

But even after a factory reset, `/data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml` contains runtime permissions (even dangerous ones) for system apps, see the default permissions: [runtime-permissions.xml](https://github.com/operando/Andorid-M-App-Permissions/blob/master/runtime-permissions.xml).

**And it happens because:**

> All the default permissions are granted from
>   `PackageManagerService`, via these two methods:
>
> ```
> newUserCreated() //this get called when new user is created   
> systemReady() //this get called when device is booted
> ```
>
> and the above methods internally invoke:
>
> `DefaultPermissionPolicy.grantDefaultPermissions();`
>
> [Have a look at How DefaultPermissionPolicy triggers](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/s?refs=grantDefaultPermissions&project=frameworks)
>
> And if you see [DefaultPermissionPolicy's implementation](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java#164), it
>   contains all the relevant method to load all type of permissions for
>   System components.
>
> Specifically `DefaultPermissionPolicy.grantDefaultPermissions()`
>   internally calls
>
> [grantPermissionsToSysComponentsAndPrivApps(userId);](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java#169)
>   [grantDefaultSystemHandlerPermissions(userId);](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java#195)
>
> and it internally invokes `grantRuntimePermissionsLPw()`, [which
>   performs all the remaining work.](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java#771)

Comment: Thanks shridutt kothari.  in the beginning, no runtime-permissions.xml, then PackageManagerService  started and generate runtime-permissions.xml. in order to understand this more clearly, can you help to point where runtime permissions granted for android.uid.system, as seen in runtime-permissions.xml file.

Comment: I found below code in RuntimePermissionPersistence class. but I havn't find where PermissionState for android.uid.system been set to granted.

Comment: final int sharedUserCount = permissionsForSharedUser.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < sharedUserCount; i++) {
                    String packageName = permissionsForSharedUser.keyAt(i);
                    List<PermissionState> permissionStates = permissionsForSharedUser.valueAt(i);
                    serializer.startTag(null, TAG_SHARED_USER);
                    serializer.attribute(null, ATTR_NAME, packageName);
                    writePermissions(serializer, permissionStates);
                    serializer.endTag(null, TAG_SHARED_USER);
                }

Comment: And also, you can find "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" defined in AndroidManifest.xml from AOSP, but can not find this permission for android.uid.system in default runtime-permissions.xml. this means not all the dangerous permission is pre-granted for android.uid.system.

Comment: @user1890874 i have updated answer to answer all your queries, have a look, it should be more than sufficient for identifying from where default system permission are coming after factory reset.

Comment: Thanks Shridutt, it's very useful for me. I looked into the source code, find this,    private void grantPermissionsToSysComponentsAndPrivApps(int userId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Granting permissions to platform components for user " + userId);
but I can not find this log after device booted.

Comment: I wrote an app,    use android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR runtime permission, and use android:persistent="true" in the manifest, then signed with system signature, at last I put this apk into priv-app dir, then reboot,  but the required runtime permission "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" didn't been granted automatically. from the AOSP, it should be granted automatically from grantPermissionsToSysComponentsAndPrivApps(userId);

Comment: @user1890874 it's not gonna work like you are expecting, grantPermissionsToSysComponentsAndPrivApps will only give permission to apps which are registered in Android framework's Manifest  (http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Already accepted this answer, thanks Shridutt.   And I found grantDefaultPermissions only call onetime, because when next time reboot, system found defaultpermissions already granted, then this function won't be called again.

Comment: can you help to answer another question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186761/check-android-process-groups

Comment: @shridutt kothari, What do you mean by "register"? At which part the apps are registered?

Answer (score 0):

[Privileged Permission Allowlisting](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist)

> Device manufacturers had little control over which **signature|privileged** permissions could be granted to privileged apps. Starting in Android 8.0, manufacturers must explicitly grant privileged permissions in the system configuration XML files in the /etc/permissions directory.

Android allow system apps present in these directories(system/product/vendor/oem/ | _ext) to whitelist their permissions via writing a XML file.

1. XML file content:
   `<permissions> <privapp-permissions package="x.y.z"> <permission name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" /> </privapp-permissions> </permissions>`
2. Android.bp file:
   `prebuilt_etc { name: "x.y.z.xml", system_ext_specific: true, src: "x.y.z.xml", sub_dir: "permissions", }`
3. Add 'x.y.z.xml' to PRODUCT_PACKAGES to make this part of final image (same as for an app)
4. On target: XML file can be found under 'partition/etc/permissions/priv-app'
5. PackageManager parse all the XML files and whitelist the permissions mentioned for the package name while install the app on boot.